# How can I check if a playa field is empty?

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, conditionals

I have a playa field product_videos and am using the following conditional to check if it is empty:

```
{if product_videos:total_children > 0}
  //do something
{/if}
```

This seems pretty straight forward to me, what am I missing?

I should add the result is that the code inside the conditional never appears despite there being entries.

I have also tried:

```
{if "{exp:playa:total_children field='product_videos'}"}
  //do something
{/if}
```

which is listed as a correct answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751781/check-playa-count-in-expression-engine), this results in a php error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: User Warning
>
> Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if
>   "exp:playa:total_children entry_id="285" field='product_videos'
>   var_prefix="playaDbig9XJo"}
>
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php
>
> Line Number: 2855

Answer (score 7, accepted):

...And as soon as I write it down in a question, I figured out my mistake.

Correct solution for future visitors was:

```
{if "{product_videos:total_children}" > 0}
  //do something
{/if}
```

Comment: I usually wait a couple of minutes before hitting submit. 90% of the time just writing my question gives me the answer. hah

Comment: @JasonVarga Seems like a good idea, I will try to remember that next time.