# Matrix < > Playa check for empty cells

Tags: matrix, playa

I am having a Matrix fieldtype with two cells: text and Playa. The text field serves as the title for different rows. It's setup like this in my code:

```
{my_matrix_field}
    <div class="products">

        <h2>{cell_1}</h2>

        <ul class="noGrid">
            {cell_2}{stash:embed name="snippets:productdiv" process="start"}{/cell_2}
        </ul>

    </div>
{/my_matrix_field}
```

I would now conditionally show or hide {cell_1} based on the results of cell_2. If for example all entries are set to closed I want the cell_1 to not display anymore.

I have tried the syntax from this [post](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13236/how-can-i-check-if-a-playa-field-is-empty), but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not super-simple. At least the solution that I came up with. It also might end up costing performance a bit.

So, first thing first: We need to see if some entries are selected, that are not closed. To do that, we could use {cell_2 var_prefix="playa" status="not closed"}{playa:entry_id}{/cell_2}. Now, you can try using that in an if statement such as:

{if '{cell_2 var_prefix="playa" status="not closed"}{playa:entry_id}{/cell_2}'}
  {cell_1}
{/if}

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
{if cell_2}<h1>{cell_1}</h1>{/if}
```

This simple conditional checks for the presence of info in cell_2 and outputs the h1 if populated otherwise it will output nothing.

Comment: It's not working. :(